# como tornar um arquivo php em imagem transparente

Tags: php

bom gente e tenho o seguinte codigo

```
<?php
$text = "meu texto para add";

$my_img = imagecreate( 200, 80 ); //width & height

$background  = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 0,   0,   255 );
$text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 255, 255, 0 );
$line_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 128, 255, 0 );
imagestring( $my_img, 4, 30, 25, $text, $text_colour );
imagesetthickness ( $my_img, 5 );
imageline( $my_img, 30, 45, 165, 45, $line_colour );

header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng( $my_img );
imagecolordeallocate( $line_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $text_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $background );
imagedestroy( $my_img );
?>
```

a duvida é a seguinte, eu queria poder usar uma imagem já existente e colocar ela porém é uma png com fundo transparente, e ao clicar em salvar em vez de salvar como .php (por parte do usuario, botão direito do mouse em cima da imagem.php e salvar como png em vez de php), e deixar esse texto por cima da imagem, com fundo transparente.

Comment: Seu texto não faz sentido algum. Tem como [edit] a pergunta e escrever usando corretamente as pontuações e formando orações completas?

Comment: basicamente fazer algo desse tipo com php, [link](https://scontent-gru2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/19113240_1965480190340348_888712294_n.png?oh=b0e3e69de3dda1053ad36a1d6d47dad7&oe=59406122)